# How to add the Material UI package to React app

Tags: reactjs, npm

I want to add material-ui/icon package to my react app. If I run `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled` in my root folder I get the following error:

`Invalid package name "material-ui/icons" of package "material-ui/icons@": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.`

I also tried to install the package with the following commands:

`yarn add @material-ui/icons`

`npm install @material-ui/core`

`npm install @emotion/react`

`yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

`npm install --save material-ui/icon`

Nothing of it worked. In the case of `yarn` I got the following error `zsh: command not found: yarn` because I don't have yarn installed. How can I install the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `npm install @emotion/react @emotion/styled @mui/icons-material @mui/material`

Answer (score 0):

Running the command below will install yarn.

sudo npm install -g yarn

And then just run the code below.

yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled